# How to code this requirement functionally in Clojure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

Looking for advice as to how to code the following in Clojure. Should I be reaching for the State Monad? Or would core.async be helpful?

I need to compose these things called Blobs together. The important thing about a Blob is that it has *up to* two interface surfaces that can fit snugly with another Blob. When two Blobs go together they become another Blob. Some Blobs have only one surface and some don't have any - so can't be composed at all.

I need to code a function that will accept a sequence of Blobs and return a (usually) smaller sequence. This function will have tried all the possible combinations. The difficulty is that the combinations change when two Blobs fit together forming another Blob - two/three/four available surfaces reduce to zero/one/two.

The way I would code this in a language I'm more used to would be very stateful. There would be a pool of Blobs, initially empty. When a new Blob is added all the existing Blobs would line up (order doesn't matter) to check their compatibility with the new Blob. If none are compatible the Blob joins with the rest and there's no more activity. However if one is compatible then a new Blob is formed. Then of course the line up process starts all over again with this new Blob.

Just looking for some help with the direction to take with this. I'm out of ideas as to how to solve this functionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you might do it with recursion to the best of my understanding of your requirements. The key to avoiding mutable state is just to pass all of the relevant state into the next function call using an accumulator.

```
(def some-blobs
  [{:surfaces #{1}
    :data 1}
   {:surfaces #{1}
    :data 2}])

(def blob-to-merge
  {:surfaces #{1}
    :data 3})

(def blob-to-conj
  {:surfaces #{2}
    :data 4})

(def all-the-blobs (into some-blobs [blob-to-merge blob-to-conj]))

(defn combine-blobs [b1 b2]
  (let [s1 (b1 :surfaces)
        s2 (b2 :surfaces)
        s (first (clojure.set/intersection s1 s2))]
    {:surfaces (disj (clojure.set/union s1 s2)
                     s)
     :data (mapv :data [b1 b2])})) ; Some arbitrary way to combine the data

(defn share-surface? [b1 b2]
  (not-empty (clojure.set/intersection
               (b1 :surfaces)
               (b2 :surfaces))))

(defn add-blob [blob blobs]
  (loop [acc []  ; An accumulator to store processed blobs
         [b & bs] blobs] ; The blobs still to process, destructured into first and rest
    (if b ; If there is another blob to process
      (if (share-surface? b blob) ; If it shares a surface with the incoming blob
        (into acc (conj bs (combine-blobs b blob))) ; Then combine blobs and return with the other processed and unprocessed blobs
        (recur (conj acc b) ; Else return to `loop` adding the first blob to `acc`
               bs))         ; and attempt to process the rest
      (conj blobs blob)))) ; If there was no next blob to process then add the incoming blob to the original collection.

(add-blob blob-to-merge some-blobs)
; => [{:surfaces #{}, :data [1 3]}
; =>  {:surfaces #{1}, :data 2}]

(add-blob blob-to-conj some-blobs)
; => [{:surfaces #{1}, :data 1}
; =>  {:surfaces #{1}, :data 2}
; =>  {:surfaces #{2}, :data 4}]

(defn add-all-blobs
  "Add each new blob in turn to some existing blobs"
  [existing-blobs [b & bs :as new-blobs]]
  (if b ; If there is another blob to process
    (recur (add-blob b existing-blobs) ; Then recurse with the blob added
           bs)                         ; and process the rest
    existing-blobs)) ; If there was no next blob to process then return the original collection

(add-all-blobs [] all-the-blobs)
; => [{:surfaces #{}, :data [1 2]}
; =>  {:surfaces #{1}, :data 3}
; =>  {:surfaces #{2}, :data 4}]
```

Perhaps `add-all-blobs` doesn't always produce the smallest possible final list due to the order that they're added. I'm not sure if that's important to you.

Comment: Superb answer that does exactly what I wanted - in spite of the specification not exactly being nail down. I tried it with a Blob with many surfaces and it worked, merging multiple times. The data result was a bit nested so I added `flatten`, making `:data (into [] (flatten (map :data [b1 b2])))}))` the last line of `combine-blobs`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you need something state-ey like a monad.  Your fourth paragraph sounds to me like a normal functional process.  Each time you test a new blob, you can return a new collection of blobs, either with one more blob, or with one less blob but including a new blob that combines two others.   Blobs can persist over time or they can be recreated, but there is a new *collection* at every step.

The key is that what you are generating is a single sequence containing many collections of blobs, not a series of states of a single collection of blobs.

The top-level sequence might be a lazy sequence of blob collections, and you could easily code it as a potentially infinite sequence of blob collections, from which you can examine whichever blob collections you want.  This means that the fact that you have code that generates a sequence of all of your blob collections doesn't mean that you have to hold all of them in memory at once.  You might be interested only in the last one, in which case you can `drop` the rest.  This approach might make the code simpler, and in some situations, the laziness might be more efficient than if the sequence was non-lazy.

It may sound inefficient to keep recreating new collections, but it might not be; this is what Clojure is designed to do (and Clojure sometimes trades efficiency for other advantages).

The functions `for`, `reduce` and `map` might provide helpful building blocks; these will automatically produce lazy sequences.  Maybe more special-purpose tools like `filter` or `some` would be useful.